# SANE stack deploy to heroku

Tags: heroku, ember.js, deployment, sails.js

How do you deploy a SANE stack application to Heroku?

I have created a Procfile `web: node .app.js`.

In my .app.js I have `require('sane-cli')` but I do not know how to call `sane up` from this file.

I am not even sure this is the right way to go as far as deployment is concerned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like the only thing that can be done is to push the sails part of app to heroku.  Hopefully I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heroku, but I've written a blog post for deploying a SANE app to AWS.  I imagine many of the concepts should be similar.  The post is at: http://devnull.guru/deployment-of-a-sane-app-part-1/

Comment: @IanVS Thanks.  I was using heroku as a testing ground for a project that I have since developed and put on a vm that I have a bit more control over.  But that you for the post.  It is very informative.